# Adding Coordinates to Pan-Arctic Map on PlotSvalbard

Tags: r, ggplot2, gis, cartography

I've been trying to map a series of coordinates onto a pan-arctic map using PlotSvalbard.

My data is a list of decimal coordinates, each with an assigned name.

I've tried using the `transform_coord` function to map the latitudes and longitudes to the panarctic projection, but haven't been able to use it effectively.

So far, any attempt I've made puts all coordinates appear on the North Pole:

[image: plot]

```
basemap(type = "panarctic", limits = 50) +
  geom_point(data = DATA, aes(x = longitude, y = latitude), color = "red")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Same problem here. Aparently, you need to convert your lat/lon to the UTM system. `Plotsvalbard` contains a `transform_coord()` function:

```
utm_points <- transform_coord(lat=c(80,85), lon=c(0,120), 
          proj.og = "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84", 
          proj.out = "+proj=stere +lat_0=90 +lat_ts=71 +lon_0=0 +k=1 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0")

basemap("panarctic") + 
 geom_point(data = utm_points, aes(x=lon.utm, y=lat.utm))
```